# how does NEAR Protocol recommend local development?

Tags: docker, nearprotocol

*disclosure: I work with NEAR and am currently onboarding*

based on the docs ([docs.nearprotocol.com](https://docs.nearprotocol.com/)) and diving into the `nearcore/scripts` folder, looks like there are currently 5 ways to start a local node for development and testing (ie. developing DApps, integrating with or contributing to the platform) as well as validating (as part of [NEAR Stakewars](https://nearprotocol.com/stakewars/))

they all have the option of starting a Docker container or compiling and running the code natively

*(see repo on GitHub [`@nearprotocol/nearcore/scripts/start_*`](https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore/tree/master/scripts))*

the two that seem most useful to a DApp developer are

- **start_localnet** and
- **start_testnet**

the first launches a node that is totally isolated to local development while the second connects to the NEAR TestNet (via a common list of bootnodes and a telemetry URL)

> which of the above does NEAR recommend for local development?

for completeness, here all 5 startup scripts:

- **start_localnet**
  *totally isolated*, not related to NEAR TestNet at all (no bootnodes nor telemetry)
- **start_testnet**
  *connected to NEAR TestNet* via bootnodes and telemetry.  apparently can also reuse existing `genesis.json` file if found
- **start_stakewars**
  if you're participating in *NEAR Stakewars*, this is your startup script
- **start_unittest**
  used by `nearcore`, `near-bindgen` and `near-evm`
- **start_staging_testnet**
  used by `near-bindgen` examples "cross-contract-high-level"

*PSA1: `near-bindgen` has some well documented [examples](https://github.com/nearprotocol/near-bindgen/tree/master/examples) -- if you don't already, just decide now that you want to learn Rust*

*PSA2: `near-evm` seems like a proof of concept that lets you run Ethereum Smart Contracts on the NEAR Platform*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally `start_testnet` should be enough as it lets developers to deploy and test their contract on testnet, which I assume is what most developers want. However, there are certain cases where `start_localnet` is preferable. For example, if you want to use a different genesis for whatever reason (One reaons I can see is that if you want to see how much things cost with different config parameters), or if testnet is unstable, or if you want to run customized nearcore code that maybe incompatible with testnet code.